# How get next number some like sequence - Oracle PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hello in table I have data not use sequence (Row where num = 4 is deleted), How get number 4 for next insert? After insert row where num = 4, next num is 6...

eg.

```
Select 1 as num from dual
union all
Select 2 as num from dual
union all
Select 3 as num from dual
union all
Select 5 as num from dual
```

Comment: What is the business reason for doing this? If this is a primary key of some kind, typically the only thing that is important is that the number is *unique*, not that it is sequential. That is why sequence objects just keep counting up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one out:

```
WITH dat AS
(
SELECT 1 AS NUM
  FROM DUAL
 UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS NUM
  FROM DUAL
 UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS NUM
  FROM DUAL
 UNION ALL
SELECT 5 AS NUM
  FROM DUAL
)
SELECT d1.num + 1 AS next_val
  FROM dat d1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                     FROM dat d2
                    WHERE d2.num = d1.num + 1)
 ORDER BY next_val;
```

Comment: @Gnzq work fine, only I'm add min(d1.num)  to get one number!

Comment: Indeed, I made this one just for demonstration purpose. Glad it was of use.